# spacemacs で less/info のように、 1 キーボードでスクロールできるようにしたい

Tags: spacemacs

spacemacs を入れてみました。これは、コミュニティで .emacs.d を共通化・構造化していこうとしているプロジェクトだと自分は理解しています。

今、画面をスクロールするにあたって、これは vim (evil) binding ですので、そのキー操作は<kbd>C-f</kbd>に割り当てられているのですが、マニュアル的なテキストを読んでいる際には、 less や info のように、１文字キーボードでスクロールしてほしいな、と思います。

素の emacs をカスタマイズする際であるならば、空いているキーバインドに適当にスクロールの関数を割り当てれば話は終わるのですが、 spacemacs だと、 spacemacs に付属している既存の layer たちが壊れないように、キーバインドを割り当てるなどの設定をしていかなければならなさそうだ、と思っています。

## 質問

spacemacs で less や info のような1キースクロールを行いたくなった際には、どのような設定が推奨されるものなのでしょうか？

Comment: spacemacs は使っていないので的外れな質問になるかもしれませんが、キーバインド自体の方法が分からないのか、それとも既存の設定をなるべく維持したまま独自の割り当てを行う「流儀」的な話なのかがはっきりしない印象です。 / ちなみに less だと Space キーでもページスクロールできますよね？

Comment: spacemacs は evil-mode によるキーバインドを採用しており、また、独自の設定ファイル規約みたいなものを持っているため、どうやってキーを変更するものなのかが、まずわかっていないです。また、spacemacs は、独自のバインディングを数多提供しており、既存のどの layer にも干渉しないキーが何になるのか、というのも不明だなと思っています。